# Why didn't the crew just simulate Moriarty's voice?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

In [TNG: Ship in a Bottle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ship_in_a_Bottle_(Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation)), all of the command functions are locked to Moriarty's voice.

We can simulate people voices today using relative small computing power(running on laptop) and I find it hard to believe that this isn't possible with equipment in the 24th century.

**Why didn't the crew simulate Moriarty's voice to regain control of the ship?**

Comment: In the case of Data commands were locked to a specific location and code. Could've been that Moriarty also did similar with that location being the holodeck.

Comment: @JonClements completely irrelevant question is how morarity made the simulation in the first place to trick Picard into giving away his command codes?

Comment: @Pioneer- He's a genius. He asked the right questions to have the computer teach him how to hack it. Khan used precisely the same trick.

Comment: There are two very distinct questions here. One about TNG: Ship in a Bottle, the other about TNG: Brothers. I've edited out the latter which I suggest you ask as a separate question.

Answer (score 4):

The very short answer is that simulating Moriarty's voice outside the holodeck would have been pointless since he'd set a password

> **MORIARTY:** *Computer... interface with the central computer on the Enterprise.*
>
> The computer beeps.
>
> **COMPUTER VOICE:** *Interface complete.*
>
> **MORIARTY:** *Release command function lockouts... **authorization Moriarty, alpha two-four-one-five-nine.***
>
> <sup><sub>[TNG: Ship in a Bottle](http://tng.trekcore.com/episodes/scripts/238.txt)</sub></sup>

Even if they could simulate his voice perfectly, a five-digit password represents a hundred thousand possible combinations, with the added complexity of an alphabet letter at the start bringing the grand total into the millions.

Assuming the computer is happy for you to do keep trying 24/7, it would take weeks (if not months) to *say* all of the possible combinations.

---

Data simulating it inside the holodeck would have been just as useless since the combadges (and presumably the holodeck panels) were slaved to the holographic version of the ship and wouldn't have access to anything real.

> **PICARD:** *No. Thank you, Picard out.* (to the others) *Our combadges must be locked into the simulation; if that had been the
> real Commander Riker, he would have given our location as Holodeck
> Three.*

Comment: It's certainly "over" 150,000, but the actual number of possible passwords is 2.6 million (26*10^5).

Comment: @T-1000'sSon - I'm assuming the first letter has to be Alpha-Omega (e.g. 25 letters) and the other 5 have to be numbers 1-9. My maths is insufficient to work out the permutations.

Comment: @Valorum 25 * 9^5 =  1,476,225. But why only numbers 1 through 9? Why is zero excluded?

Comment: @Hans - I think we're getting hung up on the maths. I've made it more general since it's really not that important.

Comment: @Valorum Oh, I completely agree with your answer. Moriarty had set a password which was basically impossible to guess. Because to be able to *start* to guess the password you would have to know *how long* it is to begin with. Wasn't there an episode of TNG where Data locked out the main computer with an impossibly long sequence of characters?

Comment: @Hans - Password security on the Enterprise is weird. Some of the passwords are inordinately hard to guess, others are insanely easy if given enough time.

Comment: @Valorum Found it: in *Brothers* this monstrosity was used: "1-7-3-4-6-7-3-2-1-4-7-6-Charlie-3-2-7-8-9-7-7-7-6-4-3-Tango-7-3-2-Victor-7-3-1-1-7-8-8-8-7-3-2-4-7-6-7-8-9-7-6-4-3-7-6". And I have to admit your "1 through 9" seems to hold true. No zero anywhere... http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Command_authorization_code

Comment: @Hans - Now I'm just hoping that Pioneer asks a separate question about TNG: Brothers so I can post your comment as an answer :-P

Comment: @Hans - I'm tempted to ask separate questions about passwords in the 24th Century. "**Do passwords have to be be 1-9?**", "**Is it 'alpha' as in the greek letter or "A for Alpha" as in the phonetic letter?"**.

Comment: @Valorum Don't make me open a can of permutations on you...

Comment: The password used in *Brothers* seems to suggest American military letter code (Charlie, Tango, Victor) is used, not the Greek alphabet. Just imagine what a Klingon password would be like (choking sounds). Or a Breen one (static).